# How to set tablelist width for ipad?

Tags: uikit, ios6

I have a tablelist for iphone before:

```
@interface ListViewController : UITableViewController{
@end
```

And I plan to migrate to ipad target, but the width is still 320, how to change the width of ListViewController  ?